# Extracting coordinates from a geography column using Postgis and JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis

How can I extract a from latitude and longitude from a geograhy column stored in a Postgis (PostgreSQL)?

Comment: For future ref, this sort of stuff often does better on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The following query works with JDBC, returning two double values (latitude and longitude) that can be read using java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDouble(int, double):

```
select ST_X(MYGEOGRAPHY_COLUMN::geometry), ST_X(MYGEOGRAPHY_COLUMN::geometry) from MYTABLE
```

The double colon after the column's name is a casting operator that casts my **geography** column into a **geometry**

Functions reference: [ST_X](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [ST_X](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html)